# How can Apache POI open/manipulate Excel files that employ sensitivity labels

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Our software employs Apache POI to open Excel workbooks as templates, copy them and fill them with content.
I've recently come across the first Excel workbook that employed Sensitivity Labels.

Our implementation failed to manipulate these since they (at a first glance) don't seem to be in OOXML format anymore.
I couldn't match any of the crypto strategies POI offers to these labels.

I was hoping to still use POI alone to manipulate these and get around employing JNI-libraries to unlock the templates and resign them.

Does POI support these? It appears some python libs seem to be able to work with them.
Can anyone point me in the direction or a solution?
Are these labels known by a different technical name?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.